# Installing the R-package "rgeos" on linux: geos-config not found or not executable

Tags: r, package, gentoo

I am running R 3.4.1 on gentoo.
When i try to install the 'rgeos' package, i get this:

```
> install.packages("rgeos")
Installing package into ‘/home/jody/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/src/contrib/rgeos_0.4-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 255244 bytes (249 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 249 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
** package ‘rgeos’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
configure: CXX: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++
configure: rgeos: 0.4-2
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 581
checking for geos-config... no
no
configure: error: geos-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/home/jody/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgeos’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmppEeDps/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgeos") :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status
```

**(The same happens if i try to install rgeos on gentoo with R 3.5.1, and also on Centos 7.5 with R 3.5.1.)**

While there is a `rgeos/configure` which is executable in the tar file mentioned above, there is indeed no `geos-config` in there.

How can i get the `rgeos` package installed?

Is there perhaps a binary version which i could download?

Comment: From the package's DESCRIPTION: "The 'GEOS' library is external to the package, and, when installing the package from source, must be correctly installed first." The GEOS website is [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/), and they claim Gentoo has a binary package for GEOS, but right now the website seems to be down (see [here](https://infra-status.gentoo.org/#pk_campaign=err&pk_kwd=404))

Answer (score 28):

For Ubuntu (19.10 and likely onward) use:

```
sudo apt install libgeos-dev
```

Comment: For Debian too! :)

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 17):

I found the solution.

The "rgeos" package depends on libraries you have to install before running R.

In gentoo i had to do:

```
sudo emerge --ask sci-libs/geos
```

In CentOS:

```
sudo yum install geos geos-devel
```

After installing these libraries i started R and could install the 'rgeos' package without problems

Comment: For Ubuntu (19.10) it's `sudo apt install libgeos-dev`

Comment: @Cyrille, you should make this an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Droplet, but the OP is asking for Gentoo.

Comment: In the question yes, but the title doesn't reflect this and this is one of the first link when you search 'rgeos linux' or even 'rgeos ubuntu'.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and when I run `sudo yum install geos geos-devel` I get a "nothing to do" message because it's already installed

Comment: for mac: `brew install geos`

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 20.04, the solution is:

```
sudo apt install libgeos-dev
```

Comment: This has very little added value relative to @Cyrille's answer. It would have been better if you had just added this as a comment, saying that "yes, it works in 20.04, too".

Answer (score -2):

For Arch/Manjaro:

```
   sudo pacman -S geos
```